Is there a way to skip frames in beamer?
So if I have a slide of the form
\only<1-> point 1
\only<2-> point 2
\only<3-> point 3
...
\only<20-> point 20

Is there a way to delete point 2 with minimal editing on the rest of the slide? i.e not having to change each \only<i-> point i to \only<i-1-> point i?

Please add a short, but compilable test file which allows us to reproduce the problem. It should include a class, the necessary packages and a document environment.

Instead of hard-coding the overlays, you could use relative overlays. This would make it easy to remove one of the points:
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \only<+->{point 1}
%  \only<+->{point 2}
  \only<+->{point 3}
  ... 
  \only<+->{point 20}
\end{frame}

\end{document}


How do I specify relative vs hard coding?

@HaoS See the code in my answer.

Ah I get it now but that that's actually no good for me because I have
\only<1-> point 1
\only<2-> point 2
\only<3-> point 3
...
\only<20-> point 20
\only<1> \includegraphics[picture1]
\only<2> \includegraphics[picture2]
\only<3-> \includegraphics[picture3]

@HaoS The syntax \only<3-> point 3  is wrong because of the missing {}, so you will anyway have to edit it.
